# sweetalert2 input number with max attribute, error placement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

i have a sweetalert modal with `input: 'number'` and `inputAttributes:{ min: 0, max: foo }`.

the problem is, i don't know how to put the error placement if the value from the input is greater than allowed value (eg. max:2 , inputted: 3)

this is my code :

```
$(".addItem").on('click',function()
{
  var _this = $(this);
  Swal.fire({
    title :"add "+_this.data('title'),
    input : 'number',
    inputAttributes: {
       min: 0,
       max: _this.data('maximum')
    }
  });
});
```

in this case, i input "2" in the field which has max value of "1", and then an error appeared above the sweetalert modal button. i wonder how to put the error placement? using `Swal.showValidationError('bar')` inside `preConfirm:function(value){...}` doesn't work for me. thanks for the help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

nevermind, i solved this with

```
inputValidator: (value) => {
              if (value > _this.data('maximum')) {
                return 'quantity should not exceed available stock! <small>stock :'+_this.data('maximum')+'</small>'
              }
            }
```

above `inputAttribute:{foo:bar}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

```
let { value: cantidad } = await Swal.fire({
    title: "Cantidad",
    html: "Cantidad máxima: " + cantidad_existencia + "<br>&nbsp;",
    input: "number",
    inputPlaceholder: 'Cantidad',
    inputValue: 1,
    inputAttributes: {
        min: 1,
        max: cantidad_existencia,
        step: 1,
        pattern: "[0-9]{10}"
    },
    inputValidator: (value) => {
        if (value > cantidad_existencia) {
            return 'La cantidad ingresada supera a la cantidad en inventario'
        }
        if (value < 0) {
            return 'La cantidad ingresada no tiene sentido'
        }
        if (value == 0) {
            return 'No ha especificado cuanto va a comprar'
        }
    },
    confirmButtonText: `Establecer`,
})
```